# Apply same function to every field in SELECT statement

Tags: sql, teradata

For example:

SELECT 
a.column1

a.column2

a.column3

b.column1

b.column2
.
.
.
z.column3

FROM

a

LEFT OUTER JOIN

b

ON a.ID = b.ID

.
.
.
INNER JOIN

z

ON

a.ID = z.ID

I want to find the min(a.column1),min(a.column2),... etc.

Without explicitly writing out functions, since I have a lot of columns and will need to do this with a handful of other functions.  Preferably without stored procs or creating a temporary table since I would have to request permissions for that.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: I m not sure but you can use least function.

Comment: You can write a select statement that generates the string you want then copy the resulting string and run it. Or you script table select to clipboard, paste it into Excel and use excel strig functions to tack the `min()` to the outsides

Comment: Yeah, I ended up just using concatenate and search+replace in excel to brute force the right select statements.